# Updating from FIX 4.4 to FIX 5.0 sp2

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I have a test framework and i'm using "quckfixj-all" jar to test FIX 4.4 messages, but now I need FIX 5.0 SP2, can anyone please help me understand what all changes are required? Is it sufficient if I just change the jar version to latest one or do I need to take care of other things as well like dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it sufficient if I just change the jar version to latest one

Things might work out, might not but you will be in unknown territory and surely see some weird issues

> or do I need to take care of other things as well like dictionary

Yes you need to absolutely do this. First if you don't use it, Quickfix will understand only FIX4.4 structures. So it might not be able to understand FIX5.0 and might reject some or all correct messages. The jar and the data dictionary work in tandem, one without the other is incomplete. And if you have some user defined fields you would need to copy them across to your new data dictionary.